Shopify GraphQL API Pagination Stuck in Infinite Loop with Same `endCursor`
I am working with Shopify's GraphQL API to paginate through all orders using a cursor-based pagination approach.
The query successfully fetches orders in batches, and I can see the correct endCursor being returned and logged. However, my pagination is stuck in an infinite loop where it keeps fetching the same set of orders over and over again, even though I'm updating the endCursor for each query.
Here's my code for fetching orders:
async getAllOrders(session) {
  const _client = new shopify.api.clients.Graphql({ session });
  let hasNextPage = true;
  let endCursor = null; // Initialize to null to fetch the first page
  let allOrders = [];

    const query = `#graphql
      query ($cursor: String) {
        orders(first: 3, after: $cursor) {
          edges {
            node {
              id
            }
          }
          pageInfo {
            hasNextPage
            endCursor
          }
        }
      }`;

  while (hasNextPage) {
    try {
      console.log('Using EndCursor for Query:', endCursor);

      const data = await _client.query({
        data: query,
        variables: {
          cursor: endCursor,
        },
      });

      const orders = data.body.data.orders.edges.map((edge) => edge.node);
      allOrders.push(...orders); // Store the fetched orders

      await this._dao.addAllOrders(orders);

      // Update pagination state
      hasNextPage = data.body.data.orders.pageInfo.hasNextPage;
      endCursor = data.body.data.orders.pageInfo.endCursor; // Update cursor here

      // Log updated state after the query
      console.log('Updated EndCursor for Next Query:', endCursor);
      console.log('Has Next Page:', hasNextPage);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('GraphQL Error Response:', error.response); // Log the full error response
      if (error instanceof GraphqlQueryError) {
        throw new Error(
          `${error.message}\n${JSON.stringify(error.response, null, 2)}`
        );
      } else {
        throw error;
      }
    }
  }

  return allOrders;
}

Here are the logs from one of the iterations:
Using EndCursor for Query: null
Fetched Orders: [
  { id: 'gid://shopify/Order/6007911088439' },
  { id: 'gid://shopify/Order/6008818172215' }
]
Fetched EndCursor: eyJsYXN0X2lkIjo2MDA4ODE4MTcyMjE1LCJsYXN0X3ZhbHVlIjoiMjAyNC0wOC0yOCAwMzoyNToxMC4wMTU5MTkifQ==
Updated EndCursor for Next Query: eyJsYXN0X2lkIjo2MDA4ODE4MTcyMjE1LCJsYXN0X3ZhbHVlIjoiMjAyNC0wOC0yOCAwMzoyNToxMC4wMTU5MTkifQ==
Has Next Page: true
Using EndCursor for Query: eyJsYXN0X2lkIjo2MDA4ODE4MTcyMjE1LCJsYXN0X3ZhbHVlIjoiMjAyNC0wOC0yOCAwMzoyNToxMC4wMTU5MTkifQ==
Fetched Orders: [
  { id: 'gid://shopify/Order/6007911088439' },
  { id: 'gid://shopify/Order/6008818172215' }
]

As you can see, the endCursor is fetched and updated correctly, but it seems like the same orders are being fetched again with the same endCursor, causing an infinite loop.
I'm doing this in a Shopify embedded app template which uses ShopifyApp API by default.
Is there something wrong with how I am handling the pagination logic?
Why am I fetching the same orders repeatedly despite the endCursor being updated?
Any help or insight would be appreciated!

According to the Shopify API reference, it should be as this:
const data = await _client.query({
  data: {
    query: query,
    variables: {
      cursor: endCursor,
    },
  },
})

BTW according to them _client.query will be deprecated and it will replaced by _client.request
const client = new shopify.clients.Graphql({session});
const response = await client.query({
  data: {
    query: QUERY,
    variables: {first: 1},
  },
  extraHeaders: {myHeader: '1'},
  tries: 1,
});
console.log(response.body.data, response.body.extensions);

const client = new shopify.clients.Graphql({session});
const response = await client.request(QUERY, {
  variables: {first: 1},
  headers: {myHeader: '1'},
  retries: 2,
});
console.log(response.data, response.extensions);

reference: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-js/blob/main/packages/apps/shopify-api/docs/migrating-to-v9.md#using-the-new-clients

This happens on orders queries because you don't have the read_all_orders scope so you are limited to last two months (if i remember correctly).

The issue is that although the endCursor updates correctly, it doesn't go to the next pages and gets stuck in an infinite loop, repeatedly fetching the first set of products. I also have more recently created products, but they aren't being fetched either. Thanks for your answer! Do you see any issues with my approach?

The log indicates that the same set of orders is being fetched repeatedly. This means the endCursor returned by Shopify is not leading to the next page of results, which could be caused by a missing sort parameter.
Shopify's API might be sorting orders by default in a way that results in the same set of orders being fetched unless a sortKey is explicitly provided. Without an explicit sort, the results might appear random or repeatedly fetch the same batch. Consider adding sorting to the query like below:
const query = `#graphql
  query ($cursor: String) {
    orders(first: 3, after: $cursor, sortKey: PROCESSED_AT, reverse: false) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
        }
      }
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
      }
    }
  }
`;

There doesn't seem to be a direct issue in your code logic itself, but adding a sortKey for the query will likely resolve the issue of fetching the same orders repeatedly. Based on how Shopify’s pagination works, not specifying a sort can cause the API to return unexpected results.
